# Leaking around flange on inlet of water heater

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

I am having a problem with a leaky water heater. It is leaking on top around the cold water inlet. I replace the nipple, but this did not fix the issue. It appears the leak is not right around the pipe, but on the outside of the plastic flange. See picture.

Am I correct in assuming this means there is some sort of internal leak, and I should just replace the whole heater? Or could it be still be a problem with the nipple? I have already tightened it a fair bit, so don't want to overdo it.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: If you poke something down into the gap between the pipe nipple and the plastic flange does it come back wet (is that space full of water)? How about the other flanges? Is this a gas or electric heater?

Comment: Water usually flows/drips downward.  Unless the space below the plastic flange is full of water, would look above that puddle of water.  Maybe an elbow above is where the leak is.